# How can I use functions from different projects in Eclipse?

Tags: c, eclipse, project

I have 2 C projects in eclipse, each one do a specific work.(In one project I have `dataCatcherXML.c` and in the other project I have `main.c`)

The 1st take the value of some variables from a specific xml code and the other one has variables that must have the value taken in XMLdataCatcher.

Each one works in their specific project but If I merge both of the files(dataCatcherXML.c and main.c) in one project, it doesn't work.(And I don't know why)

So I decided to work with this files in different projects.

My questions is How can I use together this functions from different projects? Is it possible?

dataCatcherXML.C (As you can see here I am taking the value of bit error, bit error is a tag in a XML file)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <xmlmemory.h>
#include <parser.h>
#include <xmlstring.h>
#include "crc.h"

void XMLdataCatcher(int argc, char **argv) {

    xmlDocPtr doc;
    xmlNodePtr root;
    xmlNodePtr node;
    xmlNodePtr children;
    xmlNodePtr children2;

    doc = xmlParseFile("/home/practicante/XML/prueba1.xml");
    if (!doc) {
        printf("Error al cargar documento XML\n");
    }

    root = xmlDocGetRootElement(doc);
    node = root->xmlChildrenNode;
    while (node != NULL ) {
        children = node->xmlChildrenNode;
        while (children != NULL ) {
                   **//In this part I am taking the value of bit_error from the XML file**
            if (!(xmlStrcmp(node->name, "bit_error"))) {

                printf("%s: %s\n", node->name, xmlNodeGetContent(node));
                printf("%s\n", bit_error);
                strcpy(bit_error, xmlNodeGetContent(node));
                printf("%s\n", bit_error);
            }
            children2 = children->xmlChildrenNode;
            while (children2 != NULL ) {
                printf("%s: %s\n", children->name, xmlNodeGetContent(children));
                children2 = children2->next;
            }
            children = children->next;
        }
        node = node->next;
    }

    printf("bit_error2 = %d", 1);
}
```

main.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <xmlmemory.h>
#include "crc.h"
#include <parser.h>
#include <xmlstring.h>

#define BIT_SINCRONIA 0X47
#define PID_PAT 0X00
#define table_pat 0x00

FILE *fp2;

int main() {

    unsigned short bit_error = 0; // **This part should be: unsigned short bit error = (the value taken in dataCatcherXML)**
    bit_error = bit_error << 15;
    unsigned short init_payload = 1;
    init_payload = init_payload << 14;
    unsigned short transport_priority = 0;
    transport_priority = transport_priority << 13;
    unsigned short PID = PID_PAT;

    PID = transport_priority ^ PID;
    PID = bit_error ^ PID;
    PID = PID ^ init_payload;

    unsigned short PID1 = PID >> 8;
    unsigned short PID2 = PID;

   ......... the rest of the code is irrelevant   
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This question is very hard to understand.  I do not understand what you are asking well enough to even suggest improvements.  Consider adding some code to show what you have done. And try to re-word. ***[SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)***

Comment: I added some code.  What I have are two .c files in different projects and what I want is than they work together like they are in a same project. Sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to give a sane answer to such question, but I'll try with some variants.

Simple one: just copy (or link) the file from one project to another. You will need to remember about syncing it between two projects if any changes happens.

Do It In Eclipse Way: well, this one is kindly ironic, but if you really want to do it as Eclipse wants you to do it you can try this. Create a separate project. This project would contain only this dataCatcherXML.c. This project should compile into a static (because it's easier than shared) library, let's say: datacarcherxml.a. In other projects requiring this library you need to set dependencies on the datacatcherxml.a and add a library from other project. If you do that correctly datacatcherxml will be rebuild if required. Well, it's a little baroquesque, but what would you expect from IDE designed originally for Java? (Ok, it was a litle trolling, sorry about that).

To be honest, it would work that way for Java projects, I'm not sure about the CDT plugin. I'm using Eclipse only for Java. I'm rather old-schooler and I prefer well-configured vim for C/C++ development.